# Fast algorithm to remove odd elements from vector

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a vector of integers, I want to wrote a fast (not obvious *O(n^2)*) algorithm to remove all odd elements from it.

My idea is: iterate through vector till first odd element, then copy everything before it to the end of vector (call push_back method) and so on until we have looked through all original elements (except copied ones), then remove all of them, so that only the vector's tail survive.

I wrote the following code to implement it:

```
  void RemoveOdd(std::vector<int> *data) {

  size_t i = 0, j, start, end;
  uint l = (*data).size();
  start = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < l; ++i)
    {
      if ((*data)[i] % 2 != 0)
      {
      end = i;
      for (j = start, j < end, ++j)
        {
          (*data).push_back((*data)[j]);
        }
      start = i + 1;
      }
    }
  (*data).erase((*data).begin(), i);
  }
```

but it gives me lots of errors, which I can't fix. I'm very new to the programming, so expect that all of them are elementary and stupid.

Please help me with error corrections or another algorithm implementation. Any suggestions and explanations will be very appreciative. It is also better not to use algorithm library.

Comment: Instead of a raw loop, use `std::remove_if` (it's linear). And if you dereference the pointer allover the place, just pass a reference.

Comment: "It is also better not to use algorithm library." Why?

Comment: ^ - Why use `std::vector` at all. Write your own. Really...

Comment: Worth (1) considering running the loop from the end of the vector to the beginning to minimise the number of element moves, (2) consider building a new vector from scratch, given that the vector elements are trivially small, (3) consider using a standard approach - the remove-erase idiom springs to mind, with minor tweaking.

Comment: @acraig5075: because learning algorithms is important. The standard library is great and all, but learning how to do your own stuff when there isn't a ready-made algorithm that does exactly what you need is crucial; core algorithms are ready-made and generally battle-tested, but re-implementing them teaches you concepts that are extremely useful. This algorithm in particular is one of those that I re-wrote the most, typically with small variants that weren't covered efficiently by the standard version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't really need to `push_back` anything (or erase elements at the front, which requires repositioning all that follows) to remove elements according to a predicate... Try to understand the "classic" inplace removal algorithm (which ultimately is how `std::remove_if` is generally implemented):

```
void RemoveOdd(std::vector<int> & data) {
    int rp = 0, wp = 0, sz = data.size();
    for(; rp<sz; ++rp) {
        if(data[rp] % 2 == 0) {
            // if the element is a keeper, write it in the "write pointer" position 
            data[wp] = data[rp];
            // increment so that next good element won't overwrite this
            wp++;
        } 
    }
    // shrink to include only the good elements 
    data.resize(wp);
}
```

`rp` is the "read" pointer - it's the index to the current element; `wp` is the "write" pointer - it always points to the location where we'll write the next "good" element, which is also the "current length" of the "new" vector. Every time we have a good element we copy it in the write position and increment the write pointer. Given that `wp <= rp` always (as `rp` is incremented once at each iteration, and `wp` *at most* once per iteration), you are always overwriting either an element with itself (so no harm is done), or an element that has already been examined and either has been moved to its correct final position, or had to be discarded anyway.

This version is done with specific types (`vector<int>`), a specific predicate, with indexes and with "regular" (non-move) assignment, but can be easily generalized to any container with forward iterators (as its done in `std::remove_if`) and `erase`.

Even if the generic standard library algorithm works well in most cases, this is still an important algorithm to keep in mind, there are often cases where the generic library version isn't sufficient and knowing the underlying idea is useful to implement your own version.

Comment: I understand it -- very smart solution and clear explanation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [remove-erase idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Erase-Remove).

```
data.erase(std::remove_if(data.begin(), data.end(),
    [](int item) { return item % 2 != 0; }), data.end());
```

Answer (score 2):

Given pure algorithm implementation, you don't need to push back elements. In worst case scenario, you will do more than n^2 copy. (All odd data)

Keep two pointers: one for iterating (i), and one for placing. Iterate on all vector (i++), and if *data[I] is even, write it to *data[placed] and increment placed. At the end, reduce length to placed, all elements after are unecessary

remove_if does this for you ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
void DeleteOdd(std::vector<int> & m_vec) {
    int i= 0;
    for(i= 0; i< m_vec.size(); ++i) {
        if(m_vec[i] & 0x01)
       {
             m_vec.erase(m_vec.begin()+i);
             i--;
       } 
    }

    m_vec.resize(i);
```

}

Comment: Come on, this is O(n²).

Comment: This answer tells how NOT to solve the problem. Also "optimisations" like `m_vec[i] & 0x01` are best left to compiler. We can write `% 2` without hesitation.